# Drupal - Outputting Custom Fields & Limitting To Specific Pages

Tags: drupal-6

I've taken over the support of a Drupal 6 based site, and the client has requested I had a custom field for data input, which I have under `Content Types -> Page -> Manage Fields`, then added a new textarea field.

The data needs to print to a template file `page-models-and-prices.tpl.php`

I've looked at several solutions on how to print this, using `print`, `print_r`, `$content`, `$page` and `$node` as these have been used in other places (not on .tpl though), but none seems to work.

This seems like an incredibly simple function, but I can't get the data to print. Any ideas what I am missing? If someone could point me in the right direction, this would be most helpful, Drupal is a new CMS to me.

Aside from printing on the frontend, is there any way to limit the field usage per page? Ideally, I only want this used on one page.

Answer (score 0):

Whether this is correct or not, it works for Drupal 6. The CCK documentation was quite unhelpful for this function, perhaps due to the age of the Drupal version.

```
$result = db_query('SELECT field_shape_info_value, field_size_info_value, field_depth_info_value, field_chamber_info_value FROM {content_type_page} WHERE nid=51');
while ( $obj = db_fetch_object ($result) ) {
   $shape = $obj->field_shape_info_value;
   $size = $obj->field_size_info_value;
   $depth = $obj->field_depth_info_value;
   $chamber = $obj->field_chamber_info_value;
};
```

Then you can echo out on the page;

```
echo $shape;
```

I hope that helps someone.